# apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' makes error in build.gradle

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I have some problem about `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.
when I insert

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in `build.gradle`, it makes error

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

and when I erase that code, sync works well.
But I have to use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

because I want to make FirebaseApp notification.

If I erase that code,

Make sure to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` first

Error comes. I can't figure what should I do.

Comment: which version of `com.google.gms:google-services` are you using? try version 3.2.0

Comment: @kingston I used apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'. when I use buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}, FirebaseApp Error comes.

Comment: You need to import the implementation and to use the plugin

Comment: @kingston I can't import implementation. I think because apply plugin is outside dependencies.

Comment: What I mean is what's described here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin. But maybe you have already followed it. Anyway I don't see how you can use the plugin without adding the dependency `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: and you also need to call `firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());` in your `Application` class

Comment: @kingston Oh sorry my mistake in second comment. I mean when I use only dependency not with apply plugin.

Comment: @이준호, Do you place `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' line at the bottom of your app/build.gradle?

Comment: @kingston Thanks so much!! It works!

Comment: @ConstOrVar yeah I did. I didn't call FirebaseApp.initializeApp. Thanks for your attention! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api

Is actually referring to [dependencies **compile**](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html) use which you should replace it with `implementation` instead of `compile` and of course you should initialize FireBase first.

Don't remove:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And in `build.gradle`, change dependencies which starts by `compile` to `implementation`.

<sub>That's just a warning however which you can ignore it and replace it with `implementation` like I said</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing what you need to do:
in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    // ...
}
```

as the last line in your `build.gradle` add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

then define your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
        ...
    }
   ...
}
```

and in your `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<application
    android:name="your.packagename.MyApplication"
```